# SQL filter with exaclty list of id

Tags: mysql, sql, query-builder

Consider i have 2 tables : Tools and Tags with a ManyToMany relation.

Now consider :

- Tool1 : Tag1, Tag2
- Tool2 : Tag1, Tag2, Tag3

I wanna make a request SQL when i filter with tag1 and tag2, it return tool1 and tool2 BUT if a filter with all 3 tags i see only tool2.
I think it's not with IN in my sql query because, if i filter with all 3 tags, it returns all the tools.

I'm little bit disapointed. Thnaks if you help.

**UPDATE 1 - My Data Tables**

[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sO9o.png)

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far ?

Comment: Would you mind sharing your table structure? Can't formulate a query without know what the tables look like

Comment: You could try to use conditional aggregation such as `sum(case when id in (1, 2, 3) then 1 else 0 end) as id_count` and then use `group by` and `having`. Sample data and expected output would be helpful. Also, what if you are searching for 3 tags and tool-X has those 3 but also has tag4... would you want to include tool-X in the output?

Comment: I updated with my data tables

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't add any sample data, you can adjust the query yourself.
here are the steps:

1. Join the data tool and tag tables together, specify the column names and the keys in the join
2. concat all the keys together using either `string_agg()` if that doesn't work use the `group_concat()`
3. use the filters below to achieve the desired results

```
with main as (
select
<name_of_tool_name_column> as tool,
<name_of_tag_name_column>  as tag 
from tool
left join tag
on tool.id = tag.tool_id -- you need to adjust the join here based on the actual keys
),
all_tags as (
select
tool,
string_agg(tag, ',') as all_tags
-- if string_agg() doesn't work use the group_agg()
from main
group by 1
)
select * from all_tags where tool like '%Tag1%'
-- you can use other filters as well see below
```

this is how you can play with filters from the results of above query:

- would give you both too1 1 and tool 2

```
   select * from all_tags where tool like '%Tag1%'
```

- would give you both tool 1 and tool 2

```
    select * from all_tags where tool like '%Tag2%'
```

- would give you both tool 1 and tool 2

```
    select * from all_tags where tool like '%Tag2%' or tool like'%Tag1%'
```

- would give you only tool 2

```
    select * from all_tags where tool like '%Tag3%'
```